# How to create a new column based on matching ID's and string's in names of other columns in the same data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have tried to find a solution online but I cannot. I have a dataframe with 10 separate id columns, and 10 separate corresponding value columns for each ID. A brief example is shown below

Example:

```
player_id_1    player_1_x   player_id_2   player_2_x  shooter_id 

300               10           301           12           301

299               11           300           13           299
```

I want to create a new column that takes the value column from the corresponding match of ID's between the 'shooter_id' and any of the 'player_id' columns like below:

```
player_id_1    player_1_x   player_id_2   player_2_x  shooter_id  shooter_x

300               10           301           12           301         12 

299               11           300           13           299         11
```

I have really been struggling to make this work, I am not sure if I need to merge within itself, for loop through the dataframe, or .apply.. any insight would be very helpful!

Thank you!

Comment: Is there always a match present  in `player_id` for the corresponding `shooter_id`?

Comment: Yes there should always be a match! @ShubhamSharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's `filter` the `player_id` like columns, the use `.eq` + `idxmax` to  get the `player_id` columns where the match is found, finally use `lookup` to get values corresponding to `player_id's`:

```
c = df.filter(like='player_id')\
      .eq(df['shooter_id'], axis=0)\
      .idxmax(1).str.replace('_id', '').add('_x')

df['shooter_x'] = df.lookup(df.index, c)
```

---

```
   player_id_1  player_1_x  player_id_2  player_2_x  shooter_id  shooter_x
0          300          10          301          12         301         12
1          299          11          300          13         299         11
```

Comment: Thank you for sending me this! I am receiving the following error when running: ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence
I should specify that there are player_1_x and player_1_y columns. I planned on making shooter_x and shooter_y columns using this code

Comment: @Neel lets discuss [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219265/ds5)